# Не работает HttpSessionListener

Tags: java, java-ee, listener

Данный вопрос уже подымался [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32739957/httpsessionlistener-doesnt-work), [тут](https://coderanch.com/t/363070/java/HttpSessionListener-doesn-listens-event) и [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/java-j2ee/thread1535777-page2.html), но четкого ответа я там так и не увидел.
**Проблема:** слушатель `ShoppingCartManager` не работает.

```
public class ShoppingCartManager implements HttpSessionListener {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ShoppingCartManager.class.getName());

    @Override public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
        event.getSession().setAttribute("shoppingCart", shoppingCart);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Shopping Cart was added to the session");
    }

    @Override public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ((ShoppingCart) session.getAttribute("shoppingCart")).clear();
        session.removeAttribute("shoppingCart");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Shopping Cart was removed from the session");
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.package.listeners.ShoppingCartManager</listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Update:** Полный web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <display-name>Book Store</display-name>
    <description></description>

    <!--<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/BookStoreDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>-->

    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/BookStoreDB</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>DEVELOPER</param-name>
        <param-value>Name Surname</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>DATABASE_NAME</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc/BookStoreDB</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>LOGGER_NAME</param-name>
        <param-value>BookStoreLogger</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>populate</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.listeners.DatabaseProducer</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.listeners.LoggerProducer</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.listeners.DatabasePopulator</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>my.package.listeners.ShoppingCartManager</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>my.package.filters.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegistrServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.RegistrServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PreHomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.PreHomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PreBookInfoServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.PreBookInfoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PreBooksServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.PreBooksServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PreAccountServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.PreAccountServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.SearchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PreHomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/home.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PreAboutServlet</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/about.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ShoppingCartManager</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>my.package.servlets.ShoppingCartManager</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegistrServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/registr</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PreBookInfoServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/book</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PreBooksServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/books</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PreAccountServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/acc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PreHomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PreAboutServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/about</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ShoppingCartManager</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/to-shopping-cart</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: что значит не работает?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor не вызываются методы `sessionCreated` и `sessionDestroyed`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в логах нету соответствующих сообщений.